# Copy php variable to a JavaScript variable cause Design issue

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**This is my code **

I am sending copying data from a php variable to a JavaScript variable here

```
<?php
include('includes/config.php');
include('includes/classes/Artist.php');
include('includes/classes/Album.php');
include('includes/classes/Song.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['userLoggedIn'])){
    $userLoggedIn = $_SESSION['userLoggedIn'];
    echo "<script>userLoggedIn = '$userLoggedIn';</script>";
    // echo "<script>console.log('$userLoggedIn')</script>";
}else{
    header('location:register.php');
```

And if i use the echo statement in the if statement here
it cause this. see the left side navigation bar;
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj09I.png)

And if i don;t use the echo statement the page is fine looks like this
[Without error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBIPd.png)

Comment: I don’t understand what the error is. But I do see some potential issues in your code: 1) is `session_start()` called? Maybe it’s in config and I just cannot see it. 2) You’re probably printing that script tag too soon. I would assume (well, hope...) that there is no output (`<html><head>...`) until much later. Will a script tag before the html tag work? ...I have no idea, but I wouldn’t write it that way.

Comment: What is "this"? Have you tried comparing both outputs to spot any error?

Answer (score 1):

I can't access the picture you uploaded right now, but I saw an error

```
echo "<script> var userLoggedIn = '" . $userLoggedIn . "'; alert(userLoggedIn); </script>";
```

Change the part we print on the screen in this way, data will be displayed on the screen.

Comment: You don't have to break out of the double quotes.  `echo "<script> var userLoggedIn='$userLoggedIn';";` works just fine.  However, it would be much better to insert this into the html just before it's used

Comment: Please add some explanation - what have you changed, and why?

Comment: First of all, you need to finish the code that you started with double quotes or single quotes in the php code structure in the same way. 
-I started with double quotes after echo and
<script> var userLoggedIn = I printed
-then i finished the php variable $userLoggedIn with quotation and printed it
-dot does merge in php
-<script> = userLoggedIn =. $ variable. ; alert (you userlogge); I made </script> and combined the whole line

Screen output like this -> <script type="text/javascript"> var userLoggedIn = '1'; alert(userLoggedIn); </script>

Answer (score 0):

*I used this code inside the body of the html part and it works fine*

```
<?php
     if($userLoggedIn){
        echo "<script>userLoggedIn = '$userLoggedIn';</script>";
    }
?>
```